# Error when using when using oracle webservices proxy: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/stax2/XMLInputFactory2

Tags: java, web-services, oracle, noclassdeffounderror

When calling:

GetAccountBalanceResponse resp = services.getAccountBalance(request);

Here is the full error stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/stax2/XMLInputFactory2
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.AbstractSOAPImplementation.getStaXParsedEnvelope(AbstractSOAPImplementation.java:160)
at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.AbstractSOAPImplementation.createEnvelope(AbstractSOAPImplementation.java:55)
at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:91)
at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.getSOAPBody(MessageImpl.java:1573)
at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.StreamingSender._preHandlingHook(StreamingSender.java:711)
at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.StubBase._preHandlingHook(StubBase.java:754)
at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.StreamingSender._sendImpl(StreamingSender.java:208)
at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.StreamingSender._send(StreamingSender.java:113)
at company.bank.bbank.proxy.runtime.ServicesBinding_Stub.getAccountBalance(ServicesBinding_Stub.java:130)
at company.bank.bbank.proxy.ServicesPortClient.getAccountBalance(ServicesPortClient.java:48)
at company.bank.bbank.client.main(client.java:119)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.stax2.XMLInputFactory2
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
... 25 more
```

Comment: My useful answer : it seems you have a NoClassDefFoundError when calling GetAccountBalanceResponse...
I can't be more precise

Comment: Well thanks, but I already stated this myself in my question :)

Comment: I know... That was juste a joke to say your question was lacking precision ! We don't know any line of code, what system you're using, if you use Maven, or Ant, how you add all your libs,etc ... It's a problem with the StaxParser, a missing class. ClassLoaing problems could be tricky to resolve, and without hints, it's impossible to answer

Answer (score 2):

problem solved:

add this dependency to your project;

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search turns up http://woodstox.codehaus.org/ as a possible library include. I'm guessing you are either using this library or using something that depends on it. Download the jar file and make sure it is added to your classpath when running the application.

Probable jar file: http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/3.1.1/stax2-api-3.1.1.jar